# how to grouping by first letter in mdx ssas query

Tags: ssas, grouping, mdx

My MDX script:

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Fact Emp Violation Count] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Dim Date].[Calendar].[Year].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Warning Level].[Violance Hierarchies].[Violance Type].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Date].[Calendar].[Year].&[2015] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Violation])
```

My tables:

[image]

I want to group based on violence type first letters

My desired outputs is:

```
Year     | Violence Type | Fact Emp Violation Count

CY 2015  |       1       | 19 + 18 + 2 + 23 + (violence type begins with '1')

CY 2015  |       2       | 11 + 4 + 1 + (violence type begins with '2')
```

Thanks.

Comment: is this a real cube? interesting measures! Is violation type an attribute hierarchy?

Comment: is violation type an attribute hierarchy or a measure? ... this is important information to answer the question. Also could you paste in the mdx script that created the screenshot.

Comment: violation type is an attribute hierarchy, i edited my question and put my mdx script that created my table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to do a small cube design change for the solution to be optimal. In the DSV, add a named column and call it `[New Violance Type]`. Logic for that field is straightforward -

`=left([Violance Type], 1)`

My computing it before hand and storing that in the cube does wonders to your MDX query response time. Although it can be computed as a part of MDX too, but it decreases the performance.

Add this field to the same dimension as a new attribute hierarchy - `[dim warning level].[New Violance Type]`

Then you can use the below MDX -

```
select non empty { [measures].[fact emp violation count] } on columns, 
non empty { ([dim date].[calendar].[year].allmembers * [dim warning level].[New Violance Type].allmembers ) }  on rows 
from ( select ( { [dim date].[calendar].[year].&[2015] } ) on columns from [violation])
```

Comment: Good idea - writing this without any cube changes would be tricky and could be just a slow script.

Comment: hey sourav - you fancy working with me: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/141980/sql-report-writer-microgaming-software-systems?med=clc

Comment: @whytheq - thanks for thinking of me. Why don't we connect/talk here - linkedin.com/in/sourav-agasti-a961ab7